How can i monitor a Function App in Azure without App insights?
I have a function app in azure and this function app runs thousands of jobs.
Now at time it says the job is running and it actually hasnt ran at all or a time frame has been exceeded.I can see that on my UI.
I am looking for a way (WITHOUT having to use app insights as it crashes my app every time) to monitor when the job has been triggered to run and where in the code of the function app it is getting stuck ?
Is there a way to do this ?

You can make use of diagnostic logging, which allows to log information related to execution of the functions.

Configure the Function App to write logs to Log Analytics workspace under Diagnostic settings:



Query and analyze the logs in log Analytics workspace using KQL Query:


You can also configure the diagnostic setting to send the logs to storage account by opting for Archive to a storage account and opt for Stream to an Event Hub to send the logs to Event Hub.

Basic metrics (performance related) such as request count, execution time, error rates can be monitored under Monitoring=>Metrics of function app..



Alerts: You can configure of Alerts to monitor the function as mentioned in the article.


But i need to know why my function app did not  start ?  At times it works fine and then intermittently just doesnt start , I need to capture if there is an error ?

Check the error logs in Log stream in function app.

I have configured the function app to write logs. But from where in the portal do i do the KQL query , where can i find that ?

Navigate to Logs under Monitoring in Log Analytics workspace of your function app and use the KQL query to fetch the logs. Refer Image.

I have configured Diagnostic settings , where do i go next to get that second screen you have displayed ?

Go to log Analytics workspace in portal=> search for logs icon in the left pane=>close the welcome screen=> you will the above mentioned page.

I go to diagnostic settings and click on Log Analytics worksapce , is that correct ? where do i go next ? ca n you please set out some steps ?

Correct. when you click on log Analytics workspace, it takes you to the PAGE 1 click on view logs. you will be redirected to the PAGE 2, close the hub and it takes you to LOGS PAGE. you can use the queries to fetch the logs here.

so now i created a diagnostic setting , clicked on the defaultworkspace , clicked on View Logs , But how do i create a new query to run FunctionAppLogs ?  I cant see where i can put in the query ?

Also what is the point of opening Queries hub and reclosing it ?

I want a query out of Queries hub that will give me any errors that occurred ?

I have run some queries but I get no results , even for the last 7 days

Can you share the screenshot of the query you ran

Is the issue resolved? @Jenny
